# How to change JButton Color while pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make a Login / Register system. I'm trying to make it so **while** a button is Pressed it has a different colour instead of it being the default aqua colour.

Here is one of my JButtons

```
login = new JButton("Login");
login.setFont(f2);
Dimension size2 = login.getPreferredSize();
login.setBounds(105, 85, size2.width, size2.height);
login.addActionListener(new LoginSystem());
login.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
login.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

Any way for me to make it so it look different while pressed?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). Use insets (&other means) to make the button bigger. 2) BTW - the use of `setBounds` suggests you are a newbie. Probably best to get the fundamentals down pat before futzing with colors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a MouseAdapter you button's MouseListener.
For example:

```
login.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // do stuff here, change button background for example ...
        login.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes it so after the button is clicked it gets a different color but I want it to be **while** the button is clicked it's a different colour instead of the default aqua.